# Splitting Text and Formatting it - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a log file with three fields, the first two are userIDs and the third is an item description. Can I use a single formula to Split the text, format the first 2 items, and leave the 3rd alone?

Sample Data:
<@!9812391203019>; <@!98120319283> ; Short Description

Formula Currently used:
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(SPLIT(A3,";")),"[0-9]+"))

This works to extract the userID from the unneeded in the first two columns but will only give me numbers for the third.

Previous Formula was within the REGEXEXTRACT but it left the unneeded "<@!" and ">" in the columns which I wanted to remove.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
=Split(RegexReplace(A1,"[<@!>]",),"; ",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked! I'll need to check that one, need to learn more about REGEX

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(A1:A5, ";")), "[@!<>]", )))
```

[image]